# equation for 'perimeter of the base plus the height'

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, area

Thank you for your help. I retried the problem and the issue was my math skills.

A rectangular box has a base that is a square. The perimeter of the base plus the
height of the box is equal to 3 feet. What is the largest possible volume for such a box, and
what are its dimensions? Justify your answer.

Im having a hard time figuring out the equation for the perimeter. I tried to solve the problem by setting the perimeter equation as P = 4b + h but that didn't work. Then I tried using P = 4b + 4h but that did not turn out to be correct when I plugged in my found base and height.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you mean when you claim that “that didn't work”.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maximize the volume of the box:

$$V=b^2h\tag{1}$$ under the constraint

$$4b+h=3 \iff h=3-4b$$

Plug this expression of $h$ into (1); you will get a third degree function $V(b)$ in the single variable $b$ that you will have to maximize (the max. volume being reached for a value $b^*$ such that the derivative $V'(b^*)=0$).

Remark: The perimeter $4h+\color{red}8b$ is not useful.